# What does 小白脸 mean?

Tags: vocabulary

I recently see this word in a Chinese tv drama show. It seems degradative and refers to a man who is deceiving, but what does it exactly mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. an attractive young man, adonis
2. gigolo, toy boy

Reference:
http://baike.baidu.com/subview/165815/11056067.htm
http://emuch.net/html/200507/105329.html
http://www.hjenglish.com/new/p104009/

Answer (score 4):

I am Chinese.
Simply, This word is just say the young men didn't want to work and rely on rich women.Those men always have pretty faces. So call them 'white face men'.
In China, people consider white face is a symbol of pretty.

Answer (score 3):

小白脸 is a negative nickname for those who has knowledge or educated. It is from 白面书生. 白面 is saying that this person do not do labor work in the farm and not exposed under sun light, therefore, the face is white.

It is traditionally used by people who can not read and write, but still look down those who can.

Here is a example,

"小白脸，凭着两片子嘴，看了几本甚么书，就连升三级"

Answer (score 1):

我可以用中文回答吗哈哈？

就是不出去工作，靠女人工作养活自己的人。

Answer (score 0):

Try this dictionary, I think it is very good.

http://linedictionary.naver.com/dict.html#/cnen/entry/fae7cffb07e44298b0d516e985195bac&ts=0.06006506485385843